# Intents on child on Expandable ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello I want an intent on my expandable list view.. but every time I click on a child..
it just shows a TOAST.. and does not go on my intent.. my intents are on the last part of the code.. any help is highly appreciated..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;

public class LessonsMenu extends ExpandableListActivity implements
    OnChildClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    ExpandableListView expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();
    expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
    expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
    expandbleLis.setClickable(true);

    setGroupData();
    setChildGroupData();

    NewAdapter mNewAdapter = new NewAdapter(groupItem, childItem);
    mNewAdapter
            .setInflater(
                    (LayoutInflater)         getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),
                    this);
    getExpandableListView().setAdapter(mNewAdapter);
    expandbleLis.setOnChildClickListener(this);
}

public void setGroupData() {
    groupItem.add("Audio");
    groupItem.add("Camera");
    groupItem.add("External Storage");
    groupItem.add("Input");
    groupItem.add("Security");
    groupItem.add("Sensors");
    groupItem.add("Dalvik");
    groupItem.add("Bluetooth");
    groupItem.add("DRM");
    groupItem.add("Encryption");
    groupItem.add("Graphics");
    groupItem.add("Media");
    groupItem.add("Kernel");
    groupItem.add("Power");
}

ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void setChildGroupData() {
    ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Implementation");
    child.add("Latency Measure");
    child.add("Design");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Camera HAL3");
    child.add("HAL Subsystem");
    child.add("Metadata and Controls");
    child.add("3A Modes and State");
    child.add("Output and Cropping");
    child.add("Errors and Streams");
    child.add("Request Creation");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Device Specific Configuration");
    child.add("Typical Configuration Examples");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Key Layout Files");
    child.add("Key Character Maps Files");
    child.add("Input Device Configurations Files");
    child.add("Migration Guide");
    child.add("Keyboard Devices");
    child.add("Touch Devices");
    child.add("Dumpsys");
    child.add("Getevent");
    child.add("Validate Keymaps");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("dm-verity on boot");
    child.add("Security-Enchanced Linux");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Base Sensors");
    child.add("Composite Sensors");
    child.add("Batching Results");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Bytecode Format");
    child.add(".Dex Format");
    child.add("Instruction Formats");
    child.add("Introducing ART");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Bluetooth");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Digital Rights Management");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Encryption");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Graphics");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Media");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Kernel");
    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Power");
    childItem.add(child);
}
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int   groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // Create a switch that switches on the specific child position.
        switch(childPosition) {
        case 0:
            // Go to child #0 specific class.
            Intent child0Intent = new Intent(this, AudioImplementation.class);
            startActivity(child0Intent);
            break;
        case 1:
            // Go to child #1 specific class.
            Intent child1Intent = new Intent(this, AudioLatency.class);
            startActivity(child1Intent);
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

NewAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
public LayoutInflater minflater;
public Activity activity;

public NewAdapter(ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
    groupItem = grList;
    this.Childtem = childItem;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
    this.minflater = mInflater;
    activity = act;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groupItem.size();
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
    }
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}

}
```

childrow.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingLeft="40dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/childImage"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So the onChildClick method is not called? Did you checked it? Also where does that Toast get popped as I can't see any Toast in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that you have clickable components inside of your items.

Because of this the child click listener won't be called unless you touch the part of the item that doesn't have a component with a click listener on it(eg. outside your `TextView`)..

So if you would like to use `onChildClick` callback, then you should set your `TextView` to clickable **false** or you can make the `TextView's` width smaller so the user can press either on it either on the item base `View`.

Comment: Sir I have tried that.. or I have place the wrong code? I have edited my post again for my xml file.. please see my edit..

Comment: Ok, but in the adapter did you commented the setOnClick method for that TextView?

Comment: nope.. i dont have a comment there... i think theres something wrong with my code and it keeps calling the toast and not the onchildclick..

Comment: No problem :), just comment this line: convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
```

change into

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```